# How to integrate individually working Laravel and Vue code that does not work well together

Tags: laravel, vue.js, integration

I am trying to integrate a Laravel application I wrote and a Vue application my friend wrote together. While both work perfectly on their own, together I am getting a ton of errors. It appears that Vue and/or Laravel simply isn't seeing certain elements, and I'm not sure why.

One of the tags in my home.php:

```
<div class="start" id="inputData">
        <h1><span v-bind:title="welcomeDate">@{{welcomeMessage}}</span></h1>
</div>
```

The relevant code in vue.js, which is inside a onload() method. If I don't have onload, it throws other errors, which I can give if relevant.

```
var welcome = new Vue({
el: '#inputData',
data: {
    welcomeMessage: 'Welcome, user.',
    welcomeDate: "You loaded this page on " + new Date().toLocaleString()
}
```

});

Vue is imported in the blade for the main page, via:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.js') }}"></script>
```

The error it throws (in chrome console):

```
ReferenceError: inputData is not defined
```

I realize these are code snippets but it is a fairly big application and I don't want to give an overwhelming amount of code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The element with id "inputData". This one is not inside a php if or added dynamically?

Comment: Why do you use vue directive in your php file?

Comment: @SølveTornøe That is inside home.blade.php which is the main page for the site.

Comment: @SergeyBogdanov My friend used that for his html so I just copy pasted it in and added the @ symbol because we assumed that if it worked on raw html it would work with php as well. Is that not how it works?